# Bootstrap Carousel that shows different number of items based on screen size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using [Bootstrap's Carousel](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel) to create a dashboard that shows a bunch of [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) widgets. I've successfully implemented it so 1 chart shows up and used a bit of "chunking" logic to show 2 widgets at a time. This all works great, but I'd like to enhance things:

1. If the user has a screen size big enough to fit 2 charts, show 2 charts and paginate by 2.
2. If the user has a small screen size that only fits 1 chart, show 1 and paginate by 1.
3. If the user has a screen size < 2 up, but > 1, show 1.5 charts and paginate by 1.

I'm using AngularJS to build the HTML. It's easy enough to do #1 and #2 in separate template blocks and then show/hide based on screen size. However, I'm a bit stumped on #3. I can't figure out how to display 2 charts, but only paginate by 1.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing the following JavaScript to do this. Basically, I'm rendering two different sections (with classes .oneup and .twoup) and then adding a "preview" if .oneup is displayed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var chartBar = $('#chart-bar');

function chartPreview(firstChart) {
    var chartBarWidth = chartBar.width();
    if (chartBarWidth > 600) {
        var currentChart = $('.carousel-inner:visible .active');
        // append the next widget to the current item
        var chartToCheck = (firstChart) ? currentChart : currentChart.next();

        if (chartToCheck.next()) {
            chartToCheck.next().find('.widget').clone().appendTo(chartToCheck);
            $('.carousel-inner').css({'margin-left': '10px', 'width': '98.8%'})
        }
    } else if (chartBarWidth > 1040) {
        $('.carousel-inner').css({'margin-left': '0', 'width': '100%'})
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.widgets').sortable({
        cursor: "move",
        handle: ".heading"
    }).disableSelection();
    $('.boxes,.tasks').sortable();

    var carousel = $('.carousel');
    $(carousel).carousel({
        interval: 0
    });

    if (chartBar.width() < 1040) {
        chartBar.find('.oneup').show();
        chartPreview(true);

        carousel.bind('slide', function() {
            chartPreview(false);
        });
    } else {
        chartBar.find('.twoup').show();
    }
});
```

It'd be nice if I didn't have to render both oneup and twoup, but I'm not sure how to do that with AngularJS. Here's my oneup ng-repeat:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item chart"
         ng-repeat="widget in widgets | filter: {type: 'chart'} | orderBy: 'order'"
         ng-class="{active: $index == 0}">
        <chart class="widget" value="{{widget}}" type="{{widget.chartType}}"></chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

Versus the twoup ng-repeat:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item chart"
         ng-repeat="widget in widgets | filter: {type: 'chart'} | chunk: 2 | orderBy: 'order'"
         ng-class="{active: $index == 0}">
        <chart class="widget" value="{{widget[0]}}" type="{{widget[0].chartType}}"></chart>
        <chart class="widget" value="{{widget[1]}}" type="{{widget[1].chartType}}"></chart>
    </div>
</div>
```