# Bootstrap Carousel - Item Child Management

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the bootstrap carousel [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hacb6dcw/1/), I have 3 items in a row in items as follows:

```
<div class='item'>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-md-4 sub-item'>Sub Item</div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-md-4 sub-item'>Sub Item</div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-md-4 sub-item'>Sub Item</div>
</div>
<div class='item'>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-md-4 sub-item'>Sub Item</div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-md-4 sub-item'>Sub Item</div>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-md-4 sub-item'>Sub Item</div>
</div
```

The problem is when the screen gets small, the sub items **obviously do not come in a line**.

For example the DOM be something like (When the screen gets small):

```
<div class='item'>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-md-4 sub-item'>Sub Item</div>
</div>
<div class='item'>
    <div class='col-md-6 col-md-4 sub-item'>Sub Item</div>
</div>
```

> What I want is to is automatically fit the number of sub-items so that it can
>   fit on a screen. If the screen fits only two contents and if the current `item` has three contents, move it to upcoming carousel `item`. Possible?

Comment: This is an interesting problem. I don't immediately know the answer. I can think of a hack that might work. Create a carousel for each screen size. Mark the parent of each instance with hidden-xs, hidden-sm, hidden-md, etc. Seems like a really bad solution but it might work.

Comment: Also, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858011/bootstrap-carousel-that-shows-different-number-of-items-based-on-screen-size

Comment: What kind of answer do you require? css only? css + js? pure js? jQuery?

Comment: @Urahara, Any. But short and beautiful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with CSS only. The only thing I can imagine doing is to have a JavaScript 'hack' that checks the viewport width and removes or adds sub items accordingly. But I also think that this is not a great solution for your problem.

However, something that you can do with Bootstrap (v3) is to have three pre-defined widths, `col-sm-x`, `col-md-x` and `col-lg-x`. If you put all these classes on an element it behaves differently on different screen sizes (a.k.a. viewports).

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 sub-item">Sub item</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 sub-item">Sub item</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 sub-item">Sub item</div>
</div>
```

In the example above you will see that in a small viewport, a sub item is relatively wider than in a large viewport.

As an addition to my answer I also want to show you [Owl-Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/lazyLoad.html), in which one of the options is the number of items the carousel must show.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with two different carousels, one that is hidden in small screens but shown on large screens and another that is shown in small screens and hidden in large screens. That way, you also have more freedom with styling and customising the carousel for different screen-sizes (which is basically what Bootstrap and RWD is for, in the first place lol).

Just give different ids to the two carousels and proper media query classes like this:

`<div id="bigScreenCarousel" class="carousel slide hidden-xs" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">....</div>` <<-- For large screens having two items per slide, and

`<div id="smallScreenCarousel" class="carousel slide visible-xs" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">....</div>` <<-- For small screens having one item per slide.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/16/

Comment: This is not a good way to do it, you will be loading the entire carousel with images twice.

The best thing to do is specify 'col-xs-x' 'col-sm-x'  'col-md-x' etc for changing the number of slides displayed per screen size and 'visible-xs' etc ONLY displays something within that range. For other styling use @media queries in CSS. 

I can see no reason for changing the structure outside of bootstrap and CSS capabilities, if you insist on doing so you should use PHP or C# (Depending on your development environment)

Answer (score -2):

This option will work, but is not the best option. For example, if you need to change something in one of your items you now need to change it in the xs slider and then again in the lg slider.